# Return different type of data as per the condition

Tags: java, rest

I have a problem in which if in a method, called by a rest end point, I have an errorlog then the method should return a file. Otherwise, if everything is correct, it should return a json.

Is there any way to change return type of method as per the condition?

Comment: You can use a complex object as return type.

Comment: can u show example or refer to any example .

Comment: You could return Object type and in the caller method use instanceof (Not a good solution, but meet your needs). Looks like you have a design/architecture error in your software

Comment: You can return the JSON type and - on error - throw a custom `Exception` that provides the file.

Comment: You should provide more information for people to help you correctly. Like Giovani said, that kind of situation shouldn't arise in most scenarios if the design is well thought out. Why can't you have 2 methods instead of only a single one ? Can you modify what calls that method ?

Comment: @Mat No, two methods won't work here, because the return type is not known before the method enters. It's some sort of 'on error the method should provide some fallback information'.

Comment: why to create the 2 methods its just one rest end call which call the method and if error comes then we have to generate the error log and if not then return the json .

Comment: No my point is that a method should stay coherent in its tasks; you're asking a method to either return a json Or a log file which are both pretty different things. One thing you could have is a try/catch in that method (which returns only json) and trigger some event or notify an observer when the exception is caught. I fail to see why a single method should be returning 2 different objects.

Comment: You could also do something similar to Statement interface, where execute method returns a boolen to indicate if the result is a ResultSet or false if it is an update count. With this idea, you can create a new object with methods to return that file and another to return the json, also a method to query the return type.

Comment: @Izruo is right, you should return a JSON if all is good and throw an error if not. You don't return two different types!

Comment: @Aman you should update the question to be clear that you're referring to a REST call and its response.

Comment: @alfasin updated

Comment: REST calls are most likely asynchronous. Thus you cannot "return" anything.. Instead, you need to create a `Callback` interface and return whatever results you want through there.. For example (I am emulating server calls here): https://pastebin.com/UXmvjGKB In that example, you can see the completion block called with whatever parameters I want..

Answer (score 1):

I will start by saying that this is probably the wrong approach for your problem.  The correct approach is to throw an exception if you have an error, and deal with it using an exception handler.  Alternatively, use a call-back to handle the error case *before* returning from your method.  (That would deal with your "generate an errorlog" use-case.)

Having said that ....

Here's a "complex" object that you can use to return one of two types:

```
public class AorB {
    private final A a;
    private final B b;
    private final boolean isA;

    public AorB(A a) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = null;
        isA = true;
    }

    public AorB(B b) {
        this.a = null;
        this.b = b;
        isA = false;
    }

    public boolean isA() {
        return isA;
    }

    public A getA() {
        if (isA) {
            return a;
        } else {
            throw IllegalStateException("Not an A!")
        }
    }

    public B getB() {
        if (!isA) {
            return b;
        } else {
            throw IllegalStateException("Not a B!")
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just declare the return type as `Object` and use type casting and `instanceof` in the calling method to discriminate the returned values.

Comment: Though it's a smart workaround it's not appropriate in this case: the OP should return a valid JSON and if an error occurred he should return 500 error, not different types.

Comment: From the comments: "why to create the 2 methods its just one rest end call which call the method and if error comes then we have to generate the error log and if not then return the json" - Aman